# Reducing width of datatable, eliminating the bottom border line, and centering/aligning column names with column values

Tags: r, dt

My code and a picture of the resulting datatable is shown below.

```
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

hi <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(Sepal.Length.Average = mean(Sepal.Length), Sepal.Width.Average = mean(Sepal.Width))


datatable(hi, 
          rownames = FALSE,filter="none",options = list(dom = 't'))
```

[image: Picture of datatable]

1. How do I get rid of that bottom border line?
2. How to shrink the width of the table?
3. 'Species' column name is not aligned with its values. How do I align
   it like the other two columns? Whenever I use centering, the format
   comes out weird.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

hi <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(
    Sepal.Length.Average = mean(Sepal.Length), 
    Sepal.Width.Average = mean(Sepal.Width)
  )

callback <- 
  "$('table.dataTable.no-footer').css('border-bottom', 'none');"


datatable(
  hi, 
  rownames = FALSE, 
  width = 600,
  filter = "none", 
  callback = JS(callback),
  options = 
    list(
      dom = 't',
      columnDefs = list(
        list(targets = 0, className = "dt-right")
      )
    )
)
```

[image]

Note that bottom border still appears in the RStudio viewer, but not in a browser.